# Convergence of numerical integration with parameter in the region of integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I would like to solve the integral:

$
f(a)=\iiint\limits_{\mathcal{R}(a)}\frac{\sqrt{12\left(\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y-z}{y+z}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x-z}{x+z}\right)^2\right)}}{\exp(x+y+z)\sqrt{\left(\frac{4y(x-y)}{(x+y)^3}+\frac{4z(x-z)}{(x+z)^3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-4x(x-y)}{(x+y)^3}+\frac{4z(y-z)}{(y+z)^3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{-4y(y-z)}{(y+z)^3}-\frac{4x(x-z)}{(x+z)^3}\right)^2}}\rm{d} x \rm{d} y \rm{d}z
$

The region of integration $\mathcal{R}(a)$ is the surface:

$
\mathcal{R}(a)=\left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}, x\geq 0, y\geq 0, z\geq 0,z\leq x,z\leq y, \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\left(\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y-z}{y+z}\right)^2+\left(\frac{x-z}{x+z}\right)^2\right)}=a\right\}
$

With parameter $a\in[0,1]$.

All my efforts to solve this analytically have failed. I'm now struggling to get an accurate numerical solution.

I implemented it in Mathematica (v. 10.3) in this manner:

```
region[a_?NumericQ] =  ImplicitRegion[Sqrt[1/3 ((x - y)^2/(x + y)^2 + (x - z)^2/(x + z)^2 + (y - z)^2/(y + z)^2)] == a && x > 0 && y > 0 &&  z > 0 && z <= x && z <= y, {x, y, z}]

result = Table[{a,Re[NIntegrate[Sqrt[12 ((x - y)^2/(x + y)^2 + (x - z)^2/(x + z)^2 + (y - z)^2/(y + z)^2)]/(E^(x + y + z) Sqrt[(-((4 x (x - z))/(x + z)^3) - (4 y (y - z))/(y + z)^3)^2 + ((4 z (y - z))/(y + z)^3 - (4 x (x - y))/(x + y)^3)^2 + ((4 y (x - y))/(x + y)^3 + (4 z (x - z))/(x + z)^3)^2]), {x, y, z} [\Element] region[a]]]}, {a, 0, 1, .01}]
```

But I'm having all sort of convergence problems, 1/0 errors, accuracy, instabilities, etc you name it...

Do you know what I might be doing wrong? Do you know any work-around? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I might suggest a strategy: start with an analogous two-dimensional problem and get it working there first. Once you have the bugs ironed out of that, generalize to 3D.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewritten your definition of the region as

```
region2[a_?NumericQ]:=ImplicitRegion[2 x^3 (y-z)^2 (y+z)+2 x y (y-z)^2 z (y+z)+x^4 (3 y^2+2 y z+3 z^2)+y^2 z^2 (3 y^2+2 y z+3 z^2)+x^2 (3 y^4-2 y^3 z-18 y^2 z^2-2 y z^3+3 z^4)==3 a^2 (x+y)^2 (x+z)^2 (y+z)^2&&x>0&&y>0&&z>0&&z<=x&&z<=y,{x,y,z}]
```

That makes at least ContourPlot3D for these regions considerably faster.

Then Mathematica 10.3 can do the integration. Of course, it is time consuming.

```
NIntegrate[ Sqrt[12 ((x-y)^2/(x+y)^2+(x-z)^2/(x+z)^2+(y-z)^2/(y+z)^2)]/(E^(x+y+z) Sqrt[(-((4 x (x-z))/(x+z)^3)-(4 y (y-z))/(y+z)^3)^2+((4 z (y-z))/(y+z)^3-(4 x (x-y))/(x+y)^3)^2+((4 y (x-y))/(x+y)^3+(4 z (x-z))/(x+z)^3)^2]), {x,y,z} \[Element] region2[0.3]] // Timing

(* {166.765, 0.321009 -1.75152*10^-8 I} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest!

Your strategy really improved the calculation! The problem is that it does not work well for every value of $a$. You tried 0.3, and it works. But for very low values close to zero or higher ones, $a\leq 0.7$ for instance, then it fails.

Anyway, I observed that NIntegrate fails to converge for a certain value of $a$, but it manages for a value of $a$ close to that. I will do the "artisan work" and try to get a smooth curve with this strategy. Something like a manual adaptive algorithm. Luckily enough, the solution $f(a)$ is quite smooth and nice.